# PHP scandir() don't work when is called from other file

Tags: php, scandir

I've issue with `scandir()`, when I'm trying to call method from class that is using `scandir()` it doesn't work, witch means it doesn't see any dirs.

here's method from file `./Core.php`

```
class Core
{
    public function availableControllers()
    {   
        
        $dir = scandir(__DIR__);
        $count = count($dir);
        $i = 0;
        $availableControllers = array();
        
        while ($i < $count) {
            if (is_dir($dir[$i]) && $dir[$i] !== ".." && $dir[$i] !== ".") {
                array_push($availableControllers, $dir[$i]);
            }
            $i++;
        }
        
        return $availableControllers;
    }
```

I'm calling this method in `./Engine/ControllerLoader.php` (method `controllerValid()` use `avalibleControllers()`)

```
<?php
include  __DIR__ . "/../Core.php";
class ControllerLoader
{
    public function load()
    {
        
        $Core = new Core;
        $URI = ControllerLoader::explodeURI();
        $controller = $Core->controllerValid($URI[0]);
        $object = $Core->objectsValid($controller , $URI[2]);
        
        $controllerFullName = $controller."Controller";
        

        if( ControllerLoader::includeControllerFile() !== false && (isset($URI[1]) && is_int($URI[1])) ) 
        {
           
            ControllerLoader::includeControllerFile();
            call_user_func("$controllerFullName::monitor");            
        }
        elseif( ControllerLoader::includeControllerFile() !== false && $object !== false && (is_int($URI[3]) || !isset($URI[3])) )
        {
            ControllerLoader::includeControllerFile();
            call_user_func("$controller::$object", [$URI[3]]);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

When I'm running method `avilableControllers` from `Core.php` file works fine, but it doesn't work when `ControllerLoader`->`load()` using it(it returns empty array()). Any idea?

Comment: `__DIR__` is likely not pointing to where you had expected it to, in that second context.

Comment: @CBroe when im using strict dir like "/var/www/path/that/im/pointing/" still dosnt work

Comment: Well then maybe something in the _"(method controllerValid() use avalibleControllers())"_ part is wrong.

Comment: @CBroe I've found issue it was is_dir(). When I deleted is_dir($dir[$i]) everything works fine, but I don't understand why it makes that problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per PHP's manual:

> `__DIR__` Is the directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to
> `dirname(__FILE__)`. This directory name does not have a trailing slash
> unless it is the root directory.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php

The `scandir()` will be the directory of your  Core.php file if availableControllers() is called.

You can also just check if you are in the right folder when you are using this by doing `var_dump(__DIR__)` in the method you want to use.

Comment: I've found issue it was is_dir(). When I deleted is_dir($dir[$i]) everything works fine, but I don't understand why it makes that problem.

Comment: You want to include controllers which are files, but you are checking them if they are directories.

As they aren't a directory , your check is failing,

Comment: it was searching dirs witch have inside controllers, thanks any way for attention.